# understanding what does AngularJS $resource() returns (class or instance object)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm new in angular and now i'm studying the "$resource". But the question is not directly related with the "$resource", it is that i'm trying to figure out how to make in Angular a factory to do something similar as the concept of "class object" and "instance object" with "$resource".

What i mean is, how is it possible that if i declare a factory like:

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory('Entry', function($resource) {
return $resource('/api/entries/');
});
```

If i use the returned object from the factory, i get a "class object" and i can execute methods like

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('ResourceController',function(Entry) {

    var entries = Entry.query(function() {
    console.log(entries);
    });
});
```

BUT (this is what i can't understand), if i use "new", i get an "instance object", and then i can use new methods like "$save(), $delete() or $remove()".

How is it possible? What does the function "$resource('/api/entries/');" returns so it is possible to use it as an object and as a constructor (with "new") to get an instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javacript functions can act as object constructors (there is no "class" keyword").

The $ressource("whatever") class is not behaving like an object: the "query" method is a class method, and $save is an instance method.

```
////////////////
// Example "class" definition
////////////////

// Define constructor
var Logger = function(prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
};

// Define instance method
Logger.prototype.log = function(text) {
    console.log(this.prefix, text);
};

// Define class method ("static" method)
Logger.log = function(prefix, log) {
    console.log(prefix, log);
}

////////////////
// Example usage
////////////////

var myInstance = new Logger("Hello"); // create instance
myInstance.log('World'); // call instance method
=> Hello World

Logger.log("Hello", "World"); // call class method
=> Hello World
```

But once you can define a class, you can define a function that defines classes.

The $ressource function, is simply a function that returns a constructor.

```
var LoggerMeta = function(prefix1) {
    var Logger = function(prefix2) {
        this.prefix = prefix1 + prefix2;
    };

    Logger.prototype.log = ...; // same a before
    Logger.log = ...; // same as before

    return Logger;
};


// call function that returns a constructor function
var Logger = LoggerMeta("Hello");

// create instance
var myLogger = new Logger(" World");

// call instance method
myLogger.log("again")
=> Hello World again
```

Comment: Ok, if where you put "Printer", you mean "Logger", i do finally understand... If not, i do not know where does "Printer" come from. Thank you very much!